# Spring Validation: Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller, model

I am pretty sure that this problem has not been described here before. I am also pretty sure that it is a stupid mistake on my part.

The problem in brief:

- I have created a user login form.
- When user login information is
  either correct or fails at service layer, everything works
- When user
  input validation fails, I get the following message from spring:
  "Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name
  'AssessmentAdmin': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request
  handling"
- I then get a 400 error on the web page:"The request sent by the
  client was syntactically incorrect."

It seems to me that:

When login info is correct, the Model is not null. I can see this from the logs (see below). 
When user input does not meet validation requirements, the AOP calls to validation are all made but my controller method is not even called (again, see logs).

**JSPs**:

Login Form:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<title><spring:message code="label.login" /></title>
<style>
.error {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



 <h2 align="center">
  <spring:message code="label.login" />
 </h2>
 <h2 align="center">
  <spring:message code="${loginError}" />
 </h2>
 <form:form method="POST" action="/prototype2/xz/doXzLogin" commandName="userAdminForm">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="userName" >
      <spring:message code="label.name" />
      <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error"/>
     </form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="password">
      <spring:message code="label.password" />
      <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
     </form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="pin">
      <spring:message code="label.pin" />
      <form:errors path="pin" cssClass="error"/>
      
     </form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="pin" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Login Success Form (just a test page for now)

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<title><spring:message code="label.hello"/>:  ${userName}</title>
</head>
<body>


<h3 align="center"><spring:message code="label.hello"/>, ${userName}</h3>
  
  <form:form method="POST" action="/prototype2/performXzLogin" commandName="userAdminForm">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="userName"><spring:message code="label.name"/></form:label></td>
        <td>${userName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password"/></form:label></td>
        <td>${password}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="pin"><spring:message code="label.pin"/></form:label></td>
        <td>${pin}</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>  
</form:form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**:

```
  package com.prototype2.controller.user;

  import javax.validation.Valid;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.ui.Model;
  import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

  import com.prototype2.controller.welcome.SS;
  import com.prototype2.controller.welcome.SpringException;
  import com.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin;
  import com.prototype2.service.user.AdminUserService;
  import com.prototype2.service.user.BusinessService;

  @Controller
  public class UserControllerImpl
  {

   @Autowired
   private AdminUserService auService;

   @Autowired
   private BusinessService businessService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/xzlogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String xzLogin(Model model)
   {

    UserAdmin ua = new UserAdmin();
    model.addAttribute("userAdminForm", ua);
    model.addAttribute("loginError", "label.blank");

    SS.getLogger().debug("xxx: xzLogin done");
    return "xzlogin";

   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/doXzLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ExceptionHandler(
   { SpringException.class })
   public String doXzLogin(@Valid UserAdmin u, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult)
   {

    SS.getLogger().debug("doXzLogin xxx UserAdmin: " + u.toString());
    SS.getLogger().debug("doXzLogin xxx Model size: " + model.toString());
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
     model.addAttribute("loginError", "label.loginfailed");
     return "xzlogin";
    }
    SS.getLogger().debug("doing login: listing entries if any...");

    SS.getLogger().debug("User Logging In:   " + u.getUserName());
    try
    {

     model.addAttribute("userAdminForm", u);
     // model.addAttribute("userName", u.getUserName());

     // model.addAttribute("pin", u.getPin());

     // model.addAttribute("password", u.getPassword());

     if (auService.doAdminLogin(u))
     {

      return "xzloginresult";
     } else
     {
      model.addAttribute("loginError", "label.loginfailed");

      return "xzlogin";

     }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
     SS.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
     throw new SpringException(e.getMessage() + "Login Failed: Incorrect username, password, or pin");
    }

   }

  }
```

**ApplicationContext**:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

 <!-- i18n -->
 <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
  <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="localeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="handlerMapping"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
   <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Hibernate -->
                         ...
 
 <!--  validation -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
 
 <bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
</beans>
```

**Logs for successful login (No bugs, No problems. Model not null):**

```
>>******Controller Log: Successful login******





>>
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:00,731: Locale  en
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:02,845: xxx: xzLogin done
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,305: doXzLogin xxx UserAdmin: UserAdmin [userName=jake0, password=1234, pin=1234, id=null]
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,306: doXzLogin xxx Model size: {userAdmin=UserAdmin [userName=jake0, password=1234, pin=1234, id=null], org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userAdmin=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors}
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,311: doing login: listing entries if any...
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,313: User Logging In:   jake0
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,503: in ua service
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,504: logging in through dao :jake0 1234 1234
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,972: User Admin is UserAdmin [userName=jake0, password=1234, pin=1234, id=206]
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:47:14,974: User Admin is UserAdmin [userName=jake0, password=1234, pin=1234, id=206]
>>
>>



******Root Log (i.e., Spring Log): Successful login******
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:14,297: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:861) DispatcherServlet with name 'AssessmentAdmin' processing POST request for [/prototype2/xz/doXzLogin]
>>
    (cut for sake of brevity)
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,002: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1616) Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,003: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,004: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1241) Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'xzloginresult'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/xzloginresult.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'AssessmentAdmin'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,005: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(AbstractView.java:432) Added model object 'userAdmin' of type [jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin] to request in view with name 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,006: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(AbstractView.java:432) Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userAdmin' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,008: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(AbstractView.java:432) Added model object 'userAdminForm' of type [jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin] to request in view with name 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,010: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(AbstractView.java:432) Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userAdminForm' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,012: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:166) Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/xzloginresult.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'xzloginresult'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:47:15,046: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:996) Successfully completed request
>>
```

Logs for login with validation error (Model is null):**

```
>>******Controller Log: failed login******
>>
>>
>>[DEBUG] "jake.app" 2015-08-07 11:39:34,781: xxx: xzLogin done
>>
>>
>>
>>
>>


>>Root Log (i.e., Spring Log): failed login******
>>
>>
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,741: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,742: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478) Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.NotNullValidator'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,749: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450) Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.MinValidatorForNumber'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,755: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,756: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478) Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.MinValidatorForNumber'
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,802: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String jake.prototype2.controller.user.UserControllerImpl.doXzLogin(jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>>Field error in object 'userAdmin' on field 'pin': rejected value [0]; codes [Min.userAdmin.pin,Min.pin,Min.int,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userAdmin.pin,pin]; arguments []; default message [pin],1000]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1000]
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,807: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String jake.prototype2.controller.user.UserControllerImpl.doXzLogin(jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>>Field error in object 'userAdmin' on field 'pin': rejected value [0]; codes [Min.userAdmin.pin,Min.pin,Min.int,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userAdmin.pin,pin]; arguments []; default message [pin],1000]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1000]
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,809: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String jake.prototype2.controller.user.UserControllerImpl.doXzLogin(jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>>Field error in object 'userAdmin' on field 'pin': rejected value [0]; codes [Min.userAdmin.pin,Min.pin,Min.int,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userAdmin.pin,pin]; arguments []; default message [pin],1000]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1000]
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,812: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String jake.prototype2.controller.user.UserControllerImpl.doXzLogin(jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>>Field error in object 'userAdmin' on field 'pin': rejected value [0]; codes [Min.userAdmin.pin,Min.pin,Min.int,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userAdmin.pin,pin]; arguments []; default message [pin],1000]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1000]
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,815: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String jake.prototype2.controller.user.UserControllerImpl.doXzLogin(jake.prototype2.model.user.UserAdmin,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>>Field error in object 'userAdmin' on field 'pin': rejected value [0]; codes [Min.userAdmin.pin,Min.pin,Min.int,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userAdmin.pin,pin]; arguments []; default message [pin],1000]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1000]
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,817: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'AssessmentAdmin': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>>
>>[DEBUG] 2015-08-07 11:39:42,818: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:996) Successfully completed request
>>
>>
>>******HTTP 400 message ******
>>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
>>
>>
>>
>>
```

Comment: @Mudassar, Thank you for your attention. I have not written any transaction code as i am relying on declarative transactions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try removing the model argument in the post controller method,

Comment: Also login failure check should be a part of your validation and should be handled by BindingResults

Comment: Progress! I now get through to my method. Can I trouble you a little further? How do I now access the model so I can add     model.addAttribute("loginError", "label.loginfailed");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password check should be part of the validation via the BindingResult. Hence here in the controller method for post we manually Add JSR-303 error to BindingResult.

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
       return "xzlogin"; 
    }


model.addAttribute("userAdminForm", u); 

if (!auService.doAdminLogin(u)){
bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("userAdminForm","password","Invalid password "));
return "xzlogin"; 
                }
```

This allows Spring to display them in view via a FieldError

Comment: Definitely yes! Thanks a million.

Comment: But, without taking up too much of your time, can you explain why the model was not null when validation passed but null when it failed? Also why did this lead to a failure to even call the controller method doXzLogin. I love AOP, but at times it is very opaque